# VirtualBox GDB stub

Tags: gdb, virtualbox

Is there any command or a way to start VirtualBox with GDB (VirtualBox GDB stub) such as the command with QEMU.

> QEMU -s

I have found that there is a GDB stub [Here](http://sysprogs.com/VBoxGDB/), but it only works with windows.